# Testing a serviceworker using Workbox

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I have made an implementation of a service working using Google's Workbox library and I want to test my custom route handlers and logic, but I am really unsure how I can best test this. The tests should be performed in the browser because I will need to verify if the cache or my database has been modified. I also load in my custom route and handlers via a config file, so I need to make sure the correct routes are registered.

Can somebody help me point in the right direction? I have tried unit testing with Jest, but I could make the functions work which use parts of the Workbox library.

Answer (score 1):

I can point you to a few different resources, but there's no one clear best, modern way to test service worker functionality (that I'm aware of).

### The sw-appcache-behavior test suite

The [test suite](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-appcache-behavior/tree/main/tests) for `sw-appcache-behavior` is not directly related to Workbox, but it does test service worker caching behavior. The advantage of basing your tests off of this is that it's a newer and simpler codebase than Workbox, and it shows off how to run a test suite that uses [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer) to orchestrate in-browser tests, including examining cache contents after service worker event handlers have completed.

### The Workbox test suite

You could also look at how Workbox tests its own first-party code and use that as an example. I'd divide those tests up into three parts:

#### `node` unit tests

[Some tests](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/v6/test/workbox-strategies/sw/test-NetworkFirst.mjs) are run in a `node` environment using a mock service worker environment, and heavily uses `sinon` stubs to observe calls to the underlying `fetch()` and Cache Storage APIs to ensure that the expected calls are being made.

#### Current integration tests

[These tests](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/tree/v6/test/workbox-strategies/integration) rely on Selenium (wrapped via the [`selenium-assistant`](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/selenium-assistant) library) to control instances of Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. You have the advantage over the mock environment in the unit tests of actually getting test behaviors in a real browser environment. Unfortunately, there's a decent amount of [pre-test workarounds](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/v6/infra/testing/activate-sw-safari.js) and general flakiness involved in this approach to testing.

#### Future integration tests

We've been working on a modernization of the Workbox integration test suite to use [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) instead of `selenium-assistant` to orchestrate tests across Safari, Firefox, and Chrome. The resulting code ends up being much less complex, with fewer browser-specific workarounds. This is probably what I would recommend modeling a new codebase off of.

Unfortunately, we haven't had enough time to prioritize migrating the entire existing test suite over to Playwright, but you can take a look at some of what has been [migrated over in a branch](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/tree/playwright/playwright-tests), and use that as inspiration.