# Service Worker and Offline Testing: Insights and Recommendations

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I'm following up on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71938891/testing-a-serviceworker-using-workbox/72174419) regarding testing service workers. Given that two years have passed, I'm curious about any changes in the Workbox team's recommendations or practices regarding service worker testing.

Specifically, I noticed that you have been experimenting with Playwright in [this branch](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/pull/3101). I'm wondering if this indicates a shift in your testing strategy towards Playwright, especially considering its potential for testing service workers in a more stable manner.

Furthermore, Playwright has an [experimental section](https://playwright.dev/docs/service-workers-experimental) on service workers in its documentation. Is this indicative of a future direction for Playwright in service worker testing? Is it safe to use it and would you recommend using it?

Lastly, I'm currently using Cypress for testing my application in offline mode, but I've encountered limitations and inconsistencies with its support for offline tests. I'm looking for a more robust solution for testing my application's behavior in offline scenarios. Do tyou have any recommendations for a testing framework that is more suited to this purpose?

I appreciate any insights or recommendations you might have.

I tried to use Cypress for offline testing, but according to my experience it is not a viable solution. Also, tried to recreate the tests that the workbox team currently have, but they seem complex and I wanted to see their opinion before spending more time on it.